# Using panics in web application

Tags: web-applications, error-handling, go

I'm writing my web application with Go. I want to convert most of the errors from API to panics, and then catch those panics in higher-level function, log them and return error page to user.

Something like this:

```
func Handler(body func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request)) func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request) {
    return func(responseWriter http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
        defer recoverIfPanic(responseWriter, request)
        body(responseWriter, request)
    }
}

func recoverIfPanic(responseWriter http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
    reason := recover()
    if reason == nil {
        return
    }
    // log and return http error
}

func PanicIf(err error, httpStatus int, description string) {
    if error != nil {
        panic(MyPanicStruct{err: err, httpStatus: httpStatus, description: description})
    }
}
```

and in my actual code

```
result, err := SomeApi(...)
PanicIf(err, http.StatusInternalServerError, "SomeApi")
```

In 99% cases I can't do anything reasonable when, e.g. SQL server returns unexpected error or file is missing from filesystem, all I want is to log this situation and return error to user. So I can't see any reason I should return "err" unwinding stack manually, actually I'll lost stacktrace and context and it would be more difficult to find error reason.

Is there anything I miss so this approach won't work well? It seems that most Go articles recommend against using panic/recover, but I don't see why. It looks exactly like good old throw-catch mechanism in Java (and similar languages) and it works perfectly for web applications.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is there anything I miss so this approach won't work well?

That is discussed today (!) Nov. 4th, 2014, by [Dave Cheney](http://dave.cheney.net/) in "[Error handling vs. exceptions redux](http://dave.cheney.net/2014/11/04/error-handling-vs-exceptions-redux)"

> C++ exceptions, remain as difficult to use safely as they did three decades ago. When any part of your call stack can explode without warning, it is no wonder so many C++ shops mandate that exceptions not be used.

It refers to "[Why Go gets exceptions right](http://dave.cheney.net/2012/01/18/why-go-gets-exceptions-right)" (2012, pre Go1.0, but still valid today):

> Go does have a facility called `panic`, and if you squint hard enough, you might imagine that panic is the same as throw, but you’d be wrong.
>   When you throw and exception you’re making it the caller’s problem

```
throw new SomeoneElsesProblem();
```

> For example in C++ you might throw an exception when you can’t convert from an `enum` to its `string` equivalent, or in Java when parsing a date from a string.
>   In an internet connected world, where every input from a network must be considered hostile, is the failure to parse a string into a date really exceptional? Of course not.
>
> When you panic in Go, you’re freaking out, it’s not someone elses problem, it’s game over man.

```
panic("inconceivable")
```

> `panic`s are always fatal to your program.
>   **In panicing you never assume that your caller can solve the problem**. Hence panic is only used in exceptional circumstances, ones where it is not possible for your code, or anyone integrating your code to continue.
>
> The decision to not include exceptions in Go is an example of its simplicity and orthogonality. Using multiple return values and a simple convention, Go solves the problem of letting programmers know when things have gone wrong and reserves panic for the truly exceptional.

---

Other approaches, using `err` are discussed in the official wiki page "[Error handling and Go](http://blog.golang.org/error-handling-and-go)".

That being said, the article "[Defer, Panic, and Recover](http://blog.golang.org/defer-panic-and-recover)" do mention a real case for panic ([`json` package](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/), [`(d *decodeState) unmarshal` method](http://golang.org/src/pkg/encoding/json/decode.go#L131)), and add:

> The convention in the Go libraries is that even **when a package uses panic internally, its external API still presents explicit error return values**.

So if your use of panic is strictly an internal one, that could work.

Answer (score 2):

So my own personal opinion is that panic is the work of the devil and should almost never be used at all.

Having said that I wrap all my http handlers in a panic recover as there are many things (stdlib included) that panic and you have to deal with it - taking down your webserver is not a proper response - agreed.

What we've done is override our errors package with our own so when we generate an error, the error itself, with the backtrace is shot up to a site so you can log/track it there.

For example a native http implementation ->
https://deferpanic.com/help/exception-handling/native

I believe this method allows you to have your cake and eat it too without resorting to panic/recover.